# jQuery data() has an empty object, causes retrieval of data to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've encountered a very strange issue with jQuery: I previously used the data() method to get an object that is stored on the element, like this:

```
var player = $(el).data("ytPlayer");
```

However, suddenly, this is returning an undefined result.

Looking at the $(el) object during setup and initialization of the page, I see it in the list of properties:

[image]

and at this point, if I call $(el).data("ytPlayer") it works as expected and I get the object.

But later in the lifecycle of the page, when the call to data() fails, I see this in the list of properties for that element:

[image]

There's an empty object, and also you can see my desired object right below it, but I can't seem to get to it. If at this point I call $(el).data() with no parameters, I get an empty object as well.

Is there any way to trace where this empty object is coming from, and/or any way to force jQuery to ignore it to get to the object I need?

Comment: maybe you are initializing it again or overriding?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: looks like jquery 3.0.0; I can't find any scripts that are modifying either the element or the object, but i'm not the only one working on this project and it's rather large. I'm not necessarily looking for someone to give me an answer, but rather perhaps a strategy to find what could have caused this, as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: did you try a conditional (pseudocode:  if not (null or empty) .... I'm not sure of the exact syntax in this context

Comment: thanks yes, I can do a null check and that prevents any error, but it also prevents me from doing what I need to do with the retrieved object.

Comment: Check that you haven't included multiple jQuery files, for example having more than one `<script src="jquery.js">` could be a possible reason for this

Comment: you were close, thank you! there was a script that was doing another call to the same youtube api we are using for this page, so somehow it was causing conflicts. i'll post a more detailed answer shortly, many thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the best way (at least for me) to troubleshoot this problem was to remove all scripts until the call to data() worked again, then gradually add them back one at a time until it failed.

this allowed us to isolate the offending script and fix it.